# Mulesoft Dataweave Converting the key of a mapObject to lower case

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

Assume the following json with KEY1 and KEY2 in caps. KEY1 and KEY2 needs to be converted to lower case

```
 {
    "KEY1": {
        "subkey1": "subval1",
        "subkey2": "subval2"
    },
    "KEY2": {
        "subkey1": "subval1",
        "subkey2": "subval2"
    }
  }
```

this needs to be converted to the following json using data weave.

```
 {
    "key1": {
        "subkey1": "subval1",
        "subkey2": "subval2"
    },
    "key2": {
        "subkey1": "subval1",
        "subkey2": "subval2"
    }
  }
```

I tried the following DW syntax, but it did not work

```
result : payload mapObject (
  lower '$$':$
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DW you tried should work if you wrap the expression in parenthesis. This ensures that the `lower` operator is applied to each of the keys first and then that value is used in the map. So for your example:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    result : payload mapObject (
        (lower '$$') : $
    )
}
```

Interestingly enough, I get an error (`mismatched input ':' expecting ')'`) in my Transform Message using this DW syntax but I am able to run the project without complaints from Anypoint Studio and the DW runs fine. It also works in MEL with the following:

```
#[dw("{result : payload mapObject ( (lower  '$$' ) : $)}", 'application/json')]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for providing this. this worked like a charm. even i get that error in DW. but while running it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to resolve the issue.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ result: payload mapObject (
    (lower ('$$')): $
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition if need to lower case also a values then its will be like:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    result : payload mapObject (
        (lower $$) : (lower $)
    )
}
```