# How convert json object to lower case in dataweave 1.0?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

Hello I have a json file as payload and strugling to do Transformation to lower case of elements and they values.

```
{
 "Name" : "John".
 "e-mails" : ['Email1@mail.com','email2@Gmail.com']
}
```

if its no array in values then this one works fine like [where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909527/mulesoft-dataweave-converting-the-key-of-a-mapobject-to-lower-case/63619404#63619404)

but how to deal with arrays?

expected output:

```
{
 "name" : "john".
 "e-mails" : ['email1@mail.com','email2@gmail.com']
}
```

any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a recursive function to cover for the other types.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%function lowerAll(x)
        x match {
          :object ->  $ mapObject {
                (lower $$): lowerAll($) // assumes all keys are strings
          },   
          :array  ->  $ map lowerAll($),
          :string -> lower $,
          default  ->  $
        }  
---
lowerAll(payload)
```

Input:

```
{
 "Name" : "John",
 "e-mails" : ["E1mail1@mail.com","email2@Gmail.com"]
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "e-mails": [
    "e1mail1@mail.com",
    "email2@gmail.com"
  ]
}
```

Comment: should be: default  -> lower $ so key attrinbute names are lower case as well

Comment: lower is only defined for strings, which are already covered in one of the matches, so adding it to default may cause an error for some other type.

Comment: The lower operator in DataWeave 1 only accepts a string parameter. That is already catched by the branch `:string -> lower $,`. The keys are catched by the object branch, where I use lowerAll recursively in the key `(lowerAll ($$)):`. Adding it to the default can cause an error because the other branches make sure that default will not receive a string.

Comment: yes i get numbers and boolean as well, i just add separate lines for catch this, so technicaly i am covering all cases so looks it imposible to get default case but yes its working perfectly, thanks a lot again

Comment: there is no need to use lower on booleans or numbers, or to handle them differently than using `default -> $`.

Comment: for some reason if i make default as $ some key values dont turn into lower case

Comment: additional question - i have string as date-time e.g. 2020-09.01T10:00:00+00:00 - how to avoid convert T in that case?

Comment: I did an additional test and you are right. The keys are coming as type :key, so they are not cached by the :string branch, however trying to adding a :key match gives me an error. I'm not sure how to get around that.
For the date, add a condition to the string branch, or ask a new question.

Comment: I updated the solution to handle the keys as a special case.

Comment: thanks, thats why i set default: lower $ - then it able to convert all, but exclude numbers and booleans as i set them on separate line, will think about data, perhaps will convert in query exact then call stored procedure